# Convert text to dash-separated-words

Tags: php, str-replace

I have a string "Christmas Spl - Monthly" , i want to replace this string as "Christmas-Spl-Monthly"
I know it can be possible as `str_replace(" ","-", $string);` but in this string if i will apply same thing then results are like :  `Christmas-Spl---Monthly`, I want that if string exist then space between those words and rest word should be replace

I want final answer as "Christmas-Spl-Monthly"

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of regex. Find all words and then glue them together.

```php
$string = 'Christmas Spl - - Monthly';

$matches = [];
preg_match_all('/(\w+)/', $string, $matches);
$new = implode('-', $matches[1]);

echo $new;
```

> Christmas-Spl-Monthly

Comment: This will do the job but it builds an array in the background and then converts it back to string, which is a bit performance-heavy for an operation like this. Low-level string operations should be fast as they might end up being called millions of times so I'd suggest some string-level juggling instead of split + join.

Comment: Performance can be sped up when required. Since when is PHP a low level speed optimized language? KISS.

Comment: I didn't mean to sound like judging your solution but you will absolutely feel the difference when you do it this way or with just strings. PHP can do things quite fast if you write your code carefully; believe me I'm saying this to suggest improvements, not to just teach a lesson. And the lower the level of the function, the more careful about performance you should be. When you're doing something like this, even microseconds count because they will add up as you call your function within 3-4 levels of foreach. It's not just a "we'll optimize this later", it matters. Really.

Comment: First of all, it is important that the code does its job. Performance does not matter. If I want performance, I do it in assembler. If you don't like the solution, thumb it down.

Comment: It's not about me liking it or not. It's the principle. Performance matters.

Comment: Then provide a performant solution.

Answer (score 2):

Solution:

This only for dash(-)

```
    $text = preg_replace("/[-]+/i", "-", str_replace(" ","-", "Christmas Spl - Monthly"));
    echo $text;
```

If you want **multiple dash** and **space** also convert in single dash also try this

```
$text = preg_replace("/[- ]+/i", "-",  "Christmas Spl -  Monthly");
echo $text;
```

Answer (score 1):

#### function dashedName()

I have a function for this as it's quite a common thing for generating ids.

```php
function dashedName($s) {
    $s = preg_replace("/\W+/","-",$s);
    $s = trim($s,"-");
    return $s;
}
```

This replaces non-word characters to dashes as well, making the input string "id-safe". Also it removes stray dashes from the ends of the string, so you won't get results `-like-this-`.

*Side note: this implementation is a lot (~3x) faster than the accepted answer.*

Comment: Doing `return trim($s,'-');` makes it even faster to save storing it into a variable. Using single quotes avoids the interpolation parser.

Comment: Oh so now performance suddenly matters, huh? :) Double and single quotes take almost the same time, you have to do massive iterations or take very long strings to ever spot the difference. So thank you for the addition but it's clearly an ego thing, not a practical addition. Same goes for storing a variable. It's simply not the same as suggesting a solution that's 3x faster, for algorithmic reasons. Anyway: I'm happy that you're working on the speeds now.

Comment: You said, performance matters. I never said, my solution was performant, just telling an easy way or algorithm to reach the goal. I received a notification and looked over this answer. So when talking about performance, just take it serious. LOL. I need to give a thumbs up.

Comment: I belong to the secret circle of performance enthusiasts. If you're also one of us, I'm happy to notice. Just never ever scare me again with words like "speed doesn't matter" :)

Comment: Made that "Performance can be sped up when required" comment in a hurry. Light is too slow. May the Speedforce be with you.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would be to use `str_replace` twice.
First replace `-` with  and then replace  with `-`

```
str_replace(" ","-", str_replace(" - "," ", $string));
```

so the inner `str_replace` gives you `Christmas Spl Monthly` and the outer `Christmas-Spl-Monthly`

Comment: I don't want it for specific word i have multiple data so i will run a  look, some string might be similar or some not so i want to check first then replace i am not sure which form can be generated , so i want it as dynamic

for example now string is : "Christmas Spl - - Monthly"

Comment: @ShantunParmar you need to be very specific with your question. Insert the applicable scenarios.

Comment: Okay, so the best practice would be to take a look at all the possible values and create your needed `str_replace`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to first remove the hyphen from the string

```
$string = "Christmas Spl - Monthly";
$string = str_replace(" -", "", $string);
$string = str_replace(" ", "-", $string);
```

I have first removed the hyphen with the extra space then replaced space with hyphen. The desired output will be.

```
// Christmas-Spl-Monthly
```